# Laravel Language prefix with additional parameters

Tags: laravel

Quick question that is already killing me for days. 
With Laravel I am trying to use different languages.

English and Japanese

This works in the route like this.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{lang}',
    'where' => ['lang' => '(jp|en)'],
    'middleware' => 'Language'
], function() {
    Route::get('/blogs', 'BlogController@index')->name('main-blog');
    Route::get('/blog/{postId}/{postTitle}', 'BlogController@post'); 
});
```

This works when I am visiting the "/blogs" page. 
It changes between languages.

Now when I visit the "/blog/{postId}/{postTitle}" page I can't access the posted parameter anymore within my controller.

Somehow it only shows the "lang" parameter. 
What would be the right way to access a parameter when using a prefix.

When I don't use the prefix it works like a charm.

My Controller;

```
public function post($blog_id, $blog_title) 
{
    // Do something
}
```

Help is highly appreciated. 
I have been banging my head with this for days now.

Wesley

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. The route you're having trouble with is pointing to `post()` method, but your controller doesn't seem to implement one from the code you posted.

Comment: Indeed I made a mistake with writing the example. Have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the prefix parameter to specify common parameters for your grouped routes. So You need one more parameter `$lang` for this controller:

```
public function post($lang, $blog_id, $blog_title) 
{
    // Do something
}
```

With prefix parameter the routes look like these:

```
/{lang}/blogs
/{lang}/blog/{postId}/{postTitle}
```

Comment: Indeed! I should smack myself in the face. The answer was so easy, I just made a dumb mistake. Maybe better to take some off next time after hours of scripting. You are my hero! Thanks